# How to enable/disable the features depending to result of some method on adf mobile

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile

Firstly, I want to start a taskflow automatically when just application runs. Then, i m checking something and assigned result to a variable(i think that its scope must be applicationLevel)
And now, as i tried to describe on title, i want to manipulate application features(actually i mean that just disable/enable) up to that variable, such on this link: http://adf4beginners.blogspot.com/2013/02/adf-mobile-playing-around-with-features.html?showComment=1387060885861#c1358489250811721156
Is it possible? How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

in order to start a task flow when application run, you need to create a feature and go to the content tab under the created feature then create the ADF Task flow from inside the feature.

It will be automatically added to

```
Application Resources->Descriptors->ADF META-INF->adfmf-application.xml->Feature References
```

if you could see your feature there then it will start automatically when the app run.

About your second question yes it's possible:

1- create a Java class as managed bean and add it to your feature (or application if it's application scope)

2- create a variable in that class String rendered = "false";

3- right click generate accessors (make sure that notify listener check box is selected)

4- go to your component properties -> Rendered -> click on the arrow beside the textbox

5- Select your variable under the bean created under the scope of the bean.

6- run the application the component should be hidden.

7- if you changed your variable value to "true" the component will be visible again.